# Calabash-android: getting error when trying to press on object with coordinates and using 'perform_action' command

Tags: ruby, automation, output, rect, calabash-android

I’m trying to use rect output with perform action command.
For example:

```
query("* text:’Hello’", :y)
                                                                                        [
    [0] 226.0
]
```

Trying:
`perform_action('long_press_coordinate',200,y)`

And getting the error:

```
RuntimeError: Action 'long_press_coordinate' unsuccessful: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of END_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@412a8480; line: 1, column: 61] (through reference chain: sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.Command["arguments"])
```

Is it a syntax issue that I’m dealing with or is it much more?
How do I ‘’turn’ the y value to a regular number?

Answer (score -1):

I found code that works:

```
y=query("* text:’Hello’", :y)

perform_action('long_press_coordinate',200,y[0])
```

Hope it is helping.